# align-middle not working in table

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have problem, that align-middle class not working with bootstrap 4. How can I fix this problem? Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                            <div class="table table-responsive">
                                <table id="search_content" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="d-flex">
                                            <td class="col-md-4 align-middle">Pirkimo numeris</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-8 align-middle" colspan="4"><input id="numerisId" class="form-control" name="numeris" type="text"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="d-flex">
                                            <td class="col-md-4 align-middle">Pavadinimas</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-8 align-middle" colspan="4"><input id="pavadinimasId" class="form-control" name="pavadinimas" type="text" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="d-flex">
                                            <td class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                                <input id="ieskoti" class="btn btn-danger" title="Ieškoti" type="Submit" value="Ieškoti" />
                                                <input id="trinti" class="btn btn-default" title="Išvalyti" type="submit" value="Išvalyti" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Comment: can you use class text-center in the td

Answer (score 1):

`class="align-middle"` works in Bootstrap 4 and **vertically centers** the content of an element, by applying

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

on the element.

This value makes s content align along an imaginary horizontal line placed at the (vertical) middle of `<td>`s height. See [#vertical-align](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/).

The effect can only be observed on `<td>`s that are not the tallest in their parent `<tr>`.

Note there are a large number of scenarios in which placing `align-middle` class on a `<td>` does not produce an observable change. So many that enumerating them seems a waste of time. If you are trying to vertically center the contents of a `<td>` and `align-middle` does not work for you, please update your question with a live snippet demonstrating the problem and I'll update my answer with a specific method considering your case.

---

To **center `<td>` contents horizontally**, use `class="text-center"` class on the `<td>`, which applies

```
text-align: center;
```

See [#text-alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment).

---

To align a block level element inside a wider parent, use `class="mx-auto"` class, which applies:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

See [#horizontal-centering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering).

---

Edit after snippet was added: Even though you've applied `d-flex` class to the `<tr>`, your `<td>`s still have `display:table-cell`. If you want to use flexbox centering on them give `<td>`s the following classes:

```
<td class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">Ta daaa!</td>
```

... where `.align-items-center` centers vertically and `.justify-content-center` centers horizontally.

However, in this case you're using flexbox on `<table>` markup, which makes little to no sense. Considering your usage, you're probably better off using `.form-group`s.

Comment: Updated question with snippet